# Laravel - Route can't be found when I added in a request validator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, braintree

I have a function to handle payments in my app. When I change `Request $request` to `PropertyPaymentRequest $request` Is there any reason why?

```php
public function ProcessAdvertPayment(Property $property, PropertyPaymentRequest $request)
{
    $payload = $request->input('payload', false);
    $nonce = $payload['nonce'];

    $payment = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
        'amount' => 1,
        'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
        'creditCard' => [
            'number' => request('cardnumber'), 'expirationDate' => request('month').'/'.request('year'),
            "cvv" => request('cvv')
        ],
    ]);

    if ($payment->success) {
        $property->payment()->create($request);
    }

    return response()->json($payment);
}
```

**Import of the request**

```
use App\Http\Requests\PropertyPaymentRequest;
```

**Route**

```
Route::prefix('advertisement')->group(function () {
    Route::post('{property}/payment', 'API\PropertyController@ProcessAdvertPayment');
});
```

Comment: Are you maybe missing the import of your custom form request at the top of the class? Can you show how you defined your route?

Comment: I've added then @nakov

Comment: and you use a `post` method in your form to access this endpoint?

Comment: I'm just building the API so far. But yes it's a post. I'm testing in postman

Comment: and do you pass a `_token` because that might be the problem. Laravel has CSRF protection. Please post the exact error that you get.

Comment: I just get a 404 not found.

Comment: I'm not posting a CSRF in postman. But I didn't need to for the same route before I changed the request object

Comment: Unless you've used a `get` method before, than you had to use the token, more on this here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf

Comment: Nope. I didn't use the token. It was a post. I used the same url in postman

Comment: run php artisan route:list and see what you get, post it here